# question about MySQL5.7 server(Master) and a MariaDB 10.3(Slave)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-slave-replication

I have question:

I want to install a MySQL5.7 server(Master) and a MariaDB 10.3(Slave).Replay SQL(select and update) on the slave server after SQL running on the master server.get slow sql log on slave server(MariaDB).how to deployed it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some lesser-known settings that should be set on the Slave.  Pehaps you are thinking about `log_slow_slave_statements`.  More details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Note: MySQL / MariaDB / Percona -- these have diverged somewhat in what options are available.  Also, newer versions have more settings.  The above like provides my recommendations, but check the details with the manual.